# Formatting Header of SQL Developer query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using this script:

```
COLUMN c1        HEADING 'Col1'
COLUMN c2           HEADING 'Col2'
COLUMN c3   HEADING 'Col3'
select c1, c2, c3 from t1 ORDER BY c1
```

this is what it shows:

```
Col1              Col2
-------------------- --------------------
Col3                                
----------------------------------------
aaa               bbb                
qqq                                    

ccc               ddd          
rrr                                     

eee               fff         
ppp                                     


Col1              Col2
-------------------- --------------------
Col3                                
----------------------------------------
ggg               hhh             
iii                              

jjj               kkk             
lll                           

mmm               nnn               
ooo
```

As shown I don't know why the third column is displayed in a newline and why the header is repeatedly displayed every 3 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of a similar "issue" in sqlplus.

Have you tried?

```
set linesize 200;
```

edit (additionally):

I believe this removes a lot of the spacing between the columns:

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole;
```

And this will put all rows after another:

```
set pagesize 30;
```

If its still messy, try increasing the numbers

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your current output is ugly.  One workaround would be to just `UNION` the header on explicitly:

```
SELECT t.c1, t.c2, t.c3
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Col1' AS c1, 'Col2' AS c2, 'Col3' AS c3, 1 AS pos
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT c1, c2, c3, 2 AS pos
    FROM t1
) t
ORDER BY t.pos,
         t.c1
```

This should work assuming that the `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` columns are `varchar`, which is compatible with the text appearing in the header record.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to have it looking as a nice report, any ideas please?

Comment: If you want very elaborate formatting, you might do better to handle it in a tool like Java or even PHP.  Maybe someone else can give you a fix for `HEADER`.

Comment: There is no better way to use it with HEADING but avoid the issues that happened with me?